# How To Print Returned Value from PL/SQL Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle11g, return

**I have Problem with my code in PL/SQL**

> I need to return Max(Salary)
>
> Myfunction is:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION largest_salary
(j_id EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID%TYPE)
return EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE
IS
sal EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;

begin
select max(salary)
into sal
from employees
where job_id = j_id;
return sal;
end largest_salary;
```

> and when i run this query :

```
set serveroutput out

Begin
dbms_output.put_line(largest_salary('SA_REP'));
End;
```

**it doesn't show any thing , anyone can Help me get max(salary)?**

> Note :I Think it returns multiple values but i don't know how to solve it

Comment: Should be `set serveroutput on`

Comment: @KaushikNayak thank you it worked like a charm :) you can make it an answer and i'll give you credits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `set serveroutput on` instead of

`set serveroutput out`

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT largest_salary('SA_REP')
FROM dual;
```

It is not printing, but you will get result in grid.

Answer (score 0):

you must aggregate the query results, then every thing will be ok

```
select max(salary)
into sal
from employees
where job_id = j_id;
group by job_id;
```

regards